# Does polarization take place in non polarized solid?

Tags: dielectric

According to polar - non polar division polar substances like H2O have dipole moment but unpolarised matter like O2 doesn't have dipole moment I.e. Dipole moment = 0. But my question is  does polarization also takes place in them?  If not then how come their dipole moment is becoming 0?  I mean polarization is defined by dipole moment developed per unit volume. So if there is no dipole moment initially then how come they are becoming 0? And if the answer is yes I.e. Polarization tales place in non polarized substance then why are they called non polarized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpolar materials show induced dipoles, when placed in an electric field ("the electron shell is offset with respect to the nucleus"). But they do not have permanent dipoles, that align in an applied field. (So without an external field the positive center charge of the nuclei is not "offset" with respect to the center of charge of the electrons).

Therefore, polar materials show higher permittivity (as the permanent dipoles are larger than the induced dipoles, and therfore more energy is released when they align in the field).

So as to the last question: One usually talks of polar and unpolar molecules to refer to molecules with resp. without a permanent dipole moment, not of polarizable molecules (all molecules are polarizable).